# Nginx rewrite. PHP GET Parameters have part of url when in sub-directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

So, my directory structure is something like this;

**index.php**

```
location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?params=$1 last;
    }
```

**public/assets/**

```
    location /public/assets {
         rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/assets/index.php?params=$1 last;
    }
```

So, I do need 2 rewrites for this project, one for everything expect assets and one for assets. But problem comes when using Nginx. When using Nginx to rewrite **public/assets** PHP $_GET params are following:

```
Array
(
    [params] => /public/assets/css/syles.css
)
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => public
    [2] => assets
    [3] => css
    [4] => syles.css
)
```

And these are wrong. I do not want url to passed to GET. Because when using Apache I do get following result. When using Apache, code is working as it should.

```
Array
(
    [params] => css/styles.css
)
Array
(
    [0] => css
    [1] => styles.css
)
```

So, how do I can remove these "extra" parameters from url with Nginx config? Or Do I need to use PHP to remove this extra parameters if webserver is Nginx? I do not want that solution to be even proposed as solution.

So, I want get same parameters with Nginx what I do get with Aoache to be clean.

---

FYI when using Apache I have following .htaccess placed under public/assets.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?params=$1 [NC] #L
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path before rewriting contains `/public/assets/`, so the easiest way to exclude it from what is passed to `params` is to hardcode it in the regexp and only extract what you want, using something like:

```
location /public/assets {
         rewrite ^/public/assets/(.*)$ /public/assets/index.php?params=$1 last;
    }
```